# Tensorflow-Python - InvalidArgumentError - logits and labels must be of the same size, logits_size=[512, 8] labels_size=[128, 8]

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried to port the Levi-Hassner non-BN model from the rude-carnie Github project into `tf.layers` syntax which now looks like this:

```
pkeep=0.5

weight_decay = 0.0005
weights_regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(weight_decay)
weights_initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=0.01)

input_image = features["x"]

input_layer = tf.reshape(input_image, [-1, 227, 227, 3])

conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs=input_layer,
        filters=96,
        kernel_size=[7,7],
        strides=[4,4],
        padding="valid",
        kernel_initializer=weights_initializer,
        bias_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.),
        kernel_regularizer=weights_regularizer,
        activation=tf.nn.relu)
pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1,
                                pool_size=[3, 3],
                                strides=2,
                                padding="valid")
lr_n1 = tf.nn.local_response_normalization(input=pool1, depth_radius=5, alpha=0.0001, beta=0.75, name='norm1')

conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs=lr_n1,
        filters=256,
        kernel_size=[5,5],
        strides=[1,1],
        kernel_initializer=weights_initializer,
        bias_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1.),
        kernel_regularizer=weights_regularizer,
        padding="same",
        activation=tf.nn.relu)
pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2,
                                pool_size=[3, 3],
                                strides=2,
                                padding="valid")
lr_n2 = tf.nn.local_response_normalization(input=pool2, 
                                           depth_radius=5, 
                                           alpha=0.0001, 
                                           beta=0.75, 
                                           name='norm2')

conv3 = tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs=lr_n2,
        filters=384,
        kernel_size=[3,3],
        strides=[1,1],
        kernel_initializer=weights_initializer,
        bias_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.),
        kernel_regularizer=weights_regularizer,
        padding="same",
        activation=tf.nn.relu)
pool3 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv3,
                                pool_size=[3, 3],
                                strides=2,
                                padding="valid")

flat = tf.reshape(pool3, [-1, 384*6*6 ], name="reshape")

full1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=flat, units=512)
drop1 = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=full1, rate=1-pkeep, training=(mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN), name='drop1')
full2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=drop1, units=512)
drop2 = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=full2, rate=1-pkeep, training=(mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN), name='drop2')

l_weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([512, 8], mean=0.0, stddev=0.01), name='weights')
l_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[8], dtype=tf.float32), name='biases')
#logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=drop2, units=8,kernel_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(l_weights))
logits = tf.add(tf.matmul(drop2, l_weights), l_biases)

tf.logging.info("{} {} {} {}, {}, {}".format(pool1.get_shape(), pool2.get_shape(), pool3.get_shape(), flat.get_shape(), drop2.get_shape(), logits.get_shape()))

predictions = {
    # Generate predictions (for PREDICT and EVAL mode)
    "classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
    # Add `softmax_tensor` to the graph. It is used for PREDICT and by the
    # `logging_hook`.
    "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="matmul_tensor")
}

if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    export_outputs = {
            'predict_output': tf.estimator.export.PredictOutput(predictions)
    }
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions, export_outputs=export_outputs)

# Calculate Loss (for both TRAIN and EVAL modes)
onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices=tf.cast(labels, tf.int32), depth=8)
#logger.info("onehots {} logits {}".format(tf.shape(onehot_labels), tf.shape(logits)))
loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=onehot_labels, logits=logits)

# Configure the Training Op (for TRAIN mode)
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    """
    optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01,
                                           momentum=0.9,
                                           use_nesterov=True)
    """
    #optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-4)
    optimizer= tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(rho=0.95, epsilon=1e-6)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(
        loss=loss,
        global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)

  # Add evaluation metrics (for EVAL mode)
eval_metric_ops = {
    "accuracy": tf.metrics.accuracy(
        labels=labels, predictions=predictions["classes"])}
return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
    mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)
```

Running it with my `tf.Estimator` gives the error in the title.

I've checked the tensors' sizes. `conv1`'s is `(?, 56, 56, 96)`, `pool1`'s is `(?, 27, 27, 96)`, `pool2`'s is `(?, 13, 13, 256)`, `pool3`'s is `(?, 6, 6, 384)`, `flat`'s is `(?, 13824)`, `drop2`'s is `(?, 512)`, and `logits`'s is `(?, 8)`.

All the shapes seem to check out to me, or am I missing something? And since the '?' refers to the batch size which I set up as 128, is it possible that I'm setting up the `TFRecords` input function wrong?

EDIT:

With batch size being 1, I get the same error except with a twist: the `logits_size` is `[4, 8]` and the `layers_size` is `[1, 8]`

Comment: It's possible that your data is of the wrong datatype. I've had something similar when reading from TFRecord, it being read as int32 resulting in 4x the expected values. Check the shape of the images batch you're feeding and you may see that it is 4x bigger than expected.

Comment: Mine was an OpenCV float32 encoded as a bytestring then decoded as a uint32. Maybe that's why.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it really is my TFRecords reading function. I encoded my images from `float32` and read it with `uint8`.